# How do I make php page return a 503 error (or anything non-200)

Tags: php, http

A former developer wrote or client-server api in PHP.  It simply sends messages as xml using post/response in a very simplistic fashion.  The problem is that even when there is an error (ex: invalid arguments passed into the server side) we get a HTTP 200 response with a page like this

```
<h4>Unknown error!</h4>
```

In firebug I can see that the actually HTTP response is a 200.  How can we send a different response (ie:503) when we programatically detect in our php code that it is appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use PHP's `header` function to send the code (along with the HTTP version and any other headers you need). More complete info:

[When to send HTTP status code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811513/when-to-send-http-status-code)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

```
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Retry-After: 300');//300 seconds
```

Comment: Why do you hard code the HTTP/1.1 assumption in? What happens if the client is using HTTP 1.0 ?

Comment: @Pacerier so what would you do insead? How would I write this so that it covers both HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1? All the examples show it as given in the answer

Comment: I guess `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');` ?

Comment: I guess in PHP you could write it like this:

`$protocol = "HTTP/1.0";
if ( "HTTP/1.1" == $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] )
  $protocol = "HTTP/1.1";
header( "$protocol 503 Service Unavailable", true, 503 );
header( "Retry-After: 3600" );`

source: https://yoast.com/http-503-site-maintenance-seo/

Comment: "The difference between HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1 is that In To signify successful requests and to identify transmission problems, HTTP 1.0 Status codes were utilized. HTTP/1.1 supports chunk transfers, which enabled material to be streamed in chunks and extra headers to be delivered after the message body."

Answer (score 5):

I worked on a site that had been hacked and had to use HTACCESS to do this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on

 # let this (iescaped) IP address see the real site:
 # RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.45.67.89

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]

 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.php [R=503,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

On top of your script (or really, before any output is sent as a response):

`<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` or any other [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code).

Comment: This relies on PHP's ability to map the status code from the header type (special-case handling) - it really should be header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404)

Answer (score 0):

A good class for achieving this can be found here: http://www.krisjordan.com/php-class-for-http-response-status-codes/ - use it like this (before any other output):

```
<?php header(StatusCodes::httpHeaderFor(503)); ?>
```

Comment: It is better to use something like `symfony/http-foundation` https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html